# vs code , error when tried to install package

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, pip, package

**this is the full code that i want to execute:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
from numpy.lib.polynomial import poly

image = cv2.imread("cars.jpg")
box, label, count = cv.detect_common_objects(image)
output = draw_bbox(image, box, label, count)
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
print("Number of cars in this image are " +str(label.count('car')))
```

**so i did pip install tensorflow and i got an ERROR**

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\include\external\com_github_grpc_grpc\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\grpclb\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
```

Comment: You should use a virtual environnement : https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html It will install library inside a new folder and might fix this error. It's not hard to configure and it can avoid many errors

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by too long path and the issue [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6647) gives some solutions:

1. Install `tensorflow` in the folder which has shorter path. Like @Charlyroch suggested, [create an virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments) in current project, then install the required modules in it.
2. Try to use `--user` in the command to give admin permission.
3. Reinstall Python and at the last step click **[disable path length limit](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6647#issuecomment-577564381)**.

Try the above ways and see if the error goes away.